# How to convert hex string into decimal value

Tags: c#, hex, type-conversion, decimal

I tried to convert an hex string into a decimal value but it doesn't gave me the expected result

I tried `convert.toint32(hexa,16)` , `convert.todecimal(hexa)` .

I have a string look like this :

- 1 12 94 201 198

And I convert it into :

- 10C5EC9C6

And I know that the result is:

- 4502505926

I need your help

Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `System.Decimal` (C# `decimal`) type is a floating point type and does not allow the `NumberStyles.HexNumber` specifier. The range of allowed values of the `System.Int32` (C# `int`) type is not large enough for your conversion. But you can perform this conversion with the `System.Int64` (C# `long`) type:

```
string s = "10C5EC9C6";
long n = Int64.Parse(s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
'n ==> 4502505926
```

Of course you can convert the result to a `decimal` afterwards:

```
decimal d = (decimal)Int64.Parse(s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

---

Or you can directly convert the original string with decimal coded hex groups and save you the conversion to the intermediate representation as a hex string.

```
string s = "1 12 94 201 198";
string[] groups = s.Split();
long result = 0;
foreach (string hexGroup in groups) {
    result = 256 * result + Int32.Parse(hexGroup);
}
Console.WriteLine(result); // ==> 4502505926
```

Because a group represents 2 hex digits, we multiply with 16 * 16 = 256.