# converting Long hexadecimal string to decimal value

Tags: c#

I have an extra decimal string, which i have to convert to decimal value. I am doing this now. it works for smaller values , for larger values it fails.

```
long.TryParse(hexadecimalstringinput, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber, null, out convertedValue))
```

For inputs such as "FFFF_FFFF_FFFF_FFFF_FFFF" it fails. Any alternate approach for this?

Comment: is `FFFF_FFFF_FFFF_FFFF_FFFF` a valid hexadecimal string?

Comment: You would need 80 bits to store a 20 digit hex number anyway, which is too many bits for a `long`.

Comment: this might help you, have a look at below link
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27362463/8279616

Comment: maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227731/int128-in-net

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to handle such values, take a look on BigInteger:
[MSDN BigInteger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger)